# Checking validity of topological sort

Tags: graph, topological-sort

Given the following directed graph:

[image]

I determined the topological sort to be `0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4` with the values for each node being:

```
d[0] = 1
f[0] = 16

d[1] = 2
f[1] = 15

d[2] = 3
f[2] = 14

d[3] = 4
f[3] = 13

d[4] = 7
f[4] = 8

d[5] = 6
f[5] = 9

d[6] = 5
f[6] = 10

d[7] = 11
f[7] = 12
```

Where `d` is discovery-time and `f` is finishing-time.

How can I check whether the topological sort is valid or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a less coding approach to this question (since it looks like your original topological ordering was generated without code), you can go back to the definition of a topological sort. Paraphrased from [Emory University](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/323/Syllabus/Graph/DAG.html):

Topological ordering of nodes = an ordering (label) of the nodes/vertices such that for every edge (u,v) in G, u appears earlier than v in the ordering.

There's two ways that you could approach this question: from an edge perspective of a vertex perspective. I describe a naive (meaning with some additional space complexity and cleverness, you could improve on them) implementation of both below.

**Edge approach**

Iterate through the edges in G. For each edge, retrieve the index of each of its vertices in the ordering. Compared the indices. If the origin vertex isn't earlier than the destination vertex, return false. If you iterate through all of the edges without returning false, return true.

Complexity: O(E*V)

**Vertex approach**

For each vertex in your ordering, retrieve its list of outgoing edges. If any of those edges end in a vertex that precedes the current vertex in the ordering, return false. If you iterate through all the vertices without returning false, return true.

Complexity: O(V^2*E)

Answer (score 0):

With [python](https://www.python.org/) and [networkx](https://networkx.github.io), you can check it as follows:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3)])
all_topological_sorts = list(nx.algorithms.dag.all_topological_sorts(G))
print([0, 1, 2, 3] in all_topological_sorts) # True
print([2, 3, 1, 0] in all_topological_sorts) # False
```

However, note that in order to have a topological ordering, the graph must be a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG). If G is not directed, NetworkXNotImplemented will be raised. If G is not acyclic (as in your case) NetworkXUnfeasible will be raised.

See documentation [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.all_topological_sorts.html).

Comment: While this works, this is very inefficient. For a graph without any edges this will generate all O(V!) permutations.

Answer (score 0):

First, do a graph traversal to get the incoming degree of each vertex. Then start from the first vertex in your list. Every time, when we look at a vertex, we want to check two things 1) is the incoming degree of this vertex is 0? 2) is this vertex a neighbor of the previous vertex? We also want to decrement all its neighbors' incoming degree, as if we cut all edges. If we got a no from the previous questions at some point, we know that this is not a valid topological order. Otherwise, it is. This takes O(V + E) time.

Comment: This algorithm seems like O(V * E). Consider the case of a DAG induced by a lower triangular matrix. Accessing the neighbors of each node would be an O(E) operation, no?

Answer (score 0):

I made a Python implementation of each method described in this thread:

Been Cooper's Vertex Method:

```
def is_topological_order_vertex_approch(graph, node_order):
    """
    From Ben Cooper

    Runtime:
        O(V * V * E)

    References:
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174116/checking-validity-of-topological-sort
    """
    preceding = set()
    # Iterate through the vertices in your ordering.
    for node in node_order:
        # retrieve its list of outgoing edges.
        out_edges = graph.out_edges(node)
        # If any of those edges end in a vertex that precedes
        # the current vertex in the ordering, return false.
        if any(v in preceding for u, v in out_edges):
            return False
        preceding.add(node)
    # If you iterate through all the vertices without returning false,
    # return true.
    return True
```

Been Cooper's Edge Method:

```
def is_topological_order_edge_approch(graph, node_order):
    """
    From Ben Cooper

    Runtime:
        O(V * E)

    References:
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174116/checking-validity-of-topological-sort
    """
    # Iterate through the edges in G.

    node_to_index = {n: idx for idx, n in enumerate(node_order)}
    for u, v in graph.edges:
        # For each edge, retrieve the index of each of its vertices in the ordering.
        ux = node_to_index[u]
        vx = node_to_index[v]
        # Compared the indices. If the origin vertex isn't earlier than
        # the destination vertex, return false.
        if ux >= vx:
            # raise Exception
            return False
    # If you iterate through all of the edges without returning false,
    # return true.
    return True
```

zohar.kom's method:

```
def is_topological_sort_fast_approch(graph, node_order):
    """
    From zohar.kom

    Runtime:
        Claimed as O(V + E) but is actually O(V * E)
    """
    # First, do a graph traversal to get the incoming degree of each vertex.
    in_degree = dict(graph.in_degree)
    preceding = set()
    # Then start from the first vertex in your list.
    for node in node_order:
        # Every time, when we look at a vertex, we want to check two things
        # 1) is the incoming degree of this vertex is 0?
        # 2) is this vertex a neighbor of the previous vertex?
        # If we got a no from the previous questions at some point, we
        # know that this is not a valid topological order.
        neighbors = set(graph.neighbors(node))
        if in_degree[node] != 0 and not (neighbors & preceding):
            # print(f'node={node}')
            # raise Exception
            return False

        # We also want to decrement all its neighbors' incoming degree,
        # as if we cut all edges.
        for n in neighbors:
            in_degree[n] -= 1

        preceding.add(node)

    # Otherwise, it is.
    return True
```

Test Cases:

```
import networkx as nx
import tqdm
from itertools import permutations

for N in range(10):
    for f in [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.9]:
        # Random DAG
        raw = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(N, f, directed=True)
        graph = nx.DiGraph(nodes=raw.nodes())
        graph.add_edges_from([(u, v) for u, v in raw.edges() if u < v])
        all_topo_sorts = set(map(tuple, nx.all_topological_sorts(graph)))
        all_perms = list(permutations(graph.nodes()))

        for node_order in tqdm.tqdm(all_perms):
            f0 = node_order in all_topo_sorts
            f1 = is_topological_order_edge_approch(graph, node_order)
            f2 = is_topological_order_vertex_approch(graph, node_order)
            f3 = is_topological_sort_fast_approch(graph, node_order)
            assert f0 == f1 == f2 == f3
```

On average, `is_topological_order_edge_approch` is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, using the [networkx](https://networkx.org/) library, you could verify a topological sort by shoehorning your question into a *lexicographic* topological sort. Indeed, the documentation for the function networkx.lexicographical_topological_sort() mentions this usage (emphasis mine):

> Lexicographical sorting is just sorting alphabetically. It is used
> here to break ties in the topological sort and to determine a single,
> unique ordering. **This can be useful in comparing sort results.**

However, to quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting):

> A topological ordering is possible if and only if the graph has no
> directed cycles...

In your example, there are multiple directed cycles. The shortest is 2-3-7-2. We can fix this by removing a single edge, 2-3. With that in mind, consider the Python code below.

```
# Import.
import itertools
import math
import networkx
import numpy


# Define some useful functions.
def find_most_similar_topological_sort(graph:networkx.DiGraph, 
                                       candidate_order:list) -> list:
    "Find topological sort most similar to `candidate_order`."
    # Note: key will ensure that returned topological sort follows
    # candidate_order if possible, as ties are broken by node order in
    # candidate_order.
    candidatelike_generator = networkx.lexicographical_topological_sort(
        graph, key=candidate_order.index
        )
    try:
        candidatelike_order = list(candidatelike_generator)
    except networkx.NetworkXUnfeasible as original_error:
        # Note: Raise a more detailed exception than the one returned
        # by networkx.
        simple_cycles = networkx.simple_cycles(g)
        simple_cycles_as_strings = map(str, simple_cycles)
        simple_cycles_string_block = "\n  ".join(simple_cycles_as_strings)
        detailed_error = TypeError(
            f"{graph!r} contains the following simple cycles:\n"
            f"  {simple_cycles_string_block}"
            )
        raise detailed_error from original_error    
    return candidatelike_order

def verify_topological_sort(graph:networkx.DiGraph, 
                            candidate_order:list) -> bool:
    "Verify a candidate topological sort order."
    candidatelike_order = find_most_similar_topological_sort(graph, 
                                                             candidate_order)
    return (candidatelike_order == candidate_order)


# Construct your example.
g = networkx.DiGraph()
# Note: Numpy arrays are used only to make demonstrations (further 
# below) simpler.
edge_array = numpy.array(
    ((0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 7), (7, 6), (6, 5), (5, 4),
     (0, 4), (5, 0), (5, 1), (3, 6), (7, 2))
    )
g.add_edges_from(edge_array.tolist())
candidate_order_array = numpy.array((0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4))


# Evaluate (and modify) your example.
verify_topological_sort(g, candidate_order_array.tolist())  # Error.
g.remove_edge(2, 3)  # Break cycles.
verify_topological_sort(g, candidate_order_array.tolist())  # False.
candidatelike_order = find_most_similar_topological_sort(
    g, candidate_order_array.tolist()
    )
print(candidatelike_order)  # [3, 7, 6, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4]
verify_topological_sort(g, candidatelike_order)  # True.


# Add edges in reverse order and/or replace each integer with its 
# negative to demonstrate that candidate-like order remains invariant in
# all these cases.
g_reversed = networkx.DiGraph()
g_reversed.add_edges_from(reversed(edge_array.tolist()))
g_reversed.remove_edge(2, 3)  # Break cycles.
new_candidatelike_order = find_most_similar_topological_sort(
    g_reversed, candidate_order_array.tolist()
    )
new_candidatelike_order == candidatelike_order  # True.

g_negative = networkx.DiGraph()
g_negative.add_edges_from((-edge_array).tolist())
g_negative.remove_edge(-2, -3)  # Break cycles.
new_candidatelike_order_negative = find_most_similar_topological_sort(
    g_negative, (-candidate_order_array).tolist()
    )
new_candidatelike_order = [-i for i in new_candidatelike_order_negative]
new_candidatelike_order == candidatelike_order  # True.

g_negative_reversed = networkx.DiGraph()
g_negative_reversed.add_edges_from(reversed((-edge_array).tolist()))
g_negative_reversed.remove_edge(-2, -3)  # Break cycles.
new_candidatelike_order_negative = find_most_similar_topological_sort(
    g_negative_reversed, (-candidate_order_array).tolist()
    )
new_candidatelike_order = [-i for i in new_candidatelike_order_negative]
new_candidatelike_order == candidatelike_order  # True.
```